# When i run my code, after inputting a number it doesnt let me input a string, and it goes ahead

Tags: java

when i input the number it just moves ahead without letting me enter the string and shows an output
when i use sc.next();, it does not go forward without the string, but i want to use sc.nextLine(), but it is not working

```
public class project1
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        char a;
        System.out.println("Enter \n 1 for counting the total number of vowels in it \n 2 for printing the first letter of each word in a string");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        switch(n)
        {
            case 1:
            int count = 0;
            System.out.println("Input a string");
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            str = str.toLowerCase();
            for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
            {
                a = str.charAt(i);
                if(a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u')
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println("There are "+ count +" vowels in the string.");
            break;
            
            case 2:
            System.out.println("Input a string");
            String str2 = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("First letter of each word:");
            for(int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++)
            {
                a = str2.charAt(i);
                if(a == ' ')
                System.out.print(str2.charAt(i+1) + ", "); 
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sc.nextInt will only read the integer part and leave the rest on the input stream for your next scanner command. Therefor the newline character from your first entry is still available when you try to get the string input with sc.nextLine().

You could either read the entire line and convert it to an int with:

```
n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
switch(n)
```

or you could simply add a sc.nextLine() after your sc.nextInt() to consume the rest of the input line.

```
n = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
switch(n)
```

By the way, your method for writing the first letter of each word will skip the first word  and also crash if the sentence ends with a space. Maybe try String.split() instead.